# Google Compute Engine machine type comparison - slower performance with higher number of CPU and RAM storage

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am running code (particularly related to Gaussian Processes) on Google Compute Engine VMs and I am trying to reduce the overall computation time by increasing the vm's number of cores and memory. However what I notice is that when switching for example from 'n1-standard-1' to 'n1-standard-4' ([look at machine types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Compute_Engine#Regions_and_zones)) I get an overall slower performance.

Intuitively I do not understand why this is happening or if I am missing something.

Please let me know if I should provide with any further details.

Comment: Is your code single-threaded or multi-threaded ?

Comment: Single-threaded

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia is showing only basic description of machine types.
You should look at the official [Google Cloud Platform documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types#n1_machine_types).

Apart from machine type, CPU platform can also play an important role in performance. You can see it bellow the machine type, currently (July 2019) GCP offers 4 platforms:

- Skylake
- Broadwell
- Haswell
- Ivy Bridge

More info [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/cpu-platforms).

Another factor that can influence performance is the disk.

Choose [Local SSD](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/#localssds) for low latency and high IOPS.